# Javascript Focus

Tags: javascript

I am using this script for i need a focus on every alert.i tried many ways but it is not working.

script:

```
function validateTime(obj) {
    var timeValue = obj.value;
    if(timeValue == "" || timeValue.indexOf(":") < 0) {
        alert("Invalid Time format");
        obj.value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        var sHours = timeValue.split(':')[0];
        var sMinutes = timeValue.split(':')[1];
        if(sHours == "" || isNaN(sHours) || parseInt(sHours) > 23) {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            obj.value = "";

            return false;
        } else if(parseInt(sHours) == 0) sHours = "00";
        else if(sHours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
        if(sMinutes == "" || isNaN(sMinutes) || parseInt(sMinutes) > 59) {
            alert("Invalid Time format");
            return false;
        } else if(parseInt(sMinutes) == 0) sMinutes = "00";
        else if(sMinutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
        obj.value = sHours + ":" + sMinutes;
    }
    return true;
}
```

aspx:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="lblMonday" CssClass="lblMonday" runat="server" Width="55px" onchange="validateTime(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You did of course include jQuery and tried wrapping this in a document ready function ?

Comment: i tried it no need that line just remove it if possible edit my question pls

Comment: How about a little structure and consistently using curly braces.

Comment: now check my seanrio is when the user gets alert focus should come

Comment: which element should get the focus

Comment: @ArunPJohny 







See actually i have many textboxes to validate this javascript so that only i called the validate(this).if i do like your code i need write each and every javascript for all the textbox rite..i have 16 text boxes for the 16 textboxes i want to write the code a?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `obj.focus()` after each alert. As in:

```
alert("Invalid Time format");
obj.value = "";
obj.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't called the focus() method on the text element. Also it is not a good practice to mix presentation and functionality. You must not use the onchange attribute in the HTML markup.

```
document.getElementById("lblMonday").onchange = function() {
    if(!validateTime(this)) { this.focus(); }
}
```

You can remove much of the duplication by calling alert() and resetting the field's value in a single place, as in

```
document.getElementById("lblMonday").onchange = function() {
        if(!validateTime(this)) { 
            this.focus();
            this.value="";
            alert("Invalid time format"); 
        }
        else {
            //Do something else
        }
}
```

Comment: See actually i have many textboxes to validate this javascript so that only i called the validate(this).if i do like your code i need write each and every javascript for all the textbox rite..i have 16 text boxes for the 16 textboxes i want to write the code a?

Comment: No, bro. If all of your textboxes will be validated using the same code, you can select all of them using a jQuery selector and attaching the event handler. For e.g., to attach the validation handler to every text field, $("input[type='text']").click(function(e) { //validation code }); If you are not using jQuery, you must manually iterate over all input elements returned by `document.getElementsByTagName();`

Comment: Using the Selectors API, `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')` and then attach the validation handler.

Comment: can you provide me a sample